# Combine data to create new data randomly on conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge

I have encountered the following problem I want to solve in python. I want to assign parts randomly to certain containers that have a certain capacity. Here is an example with dummy data frames (with pandas) to show what I would like to achieve:

```
dfA =
   Car Container  Capcity_container Container_type
0  CAR1       E-1                  1              E
1  CAR1       A-2                  2              A
2  CAR1       B-2                  1              B
3  CAR1       A-6                  2              A
4  CAR2       B-4                  1              B
5  CAR2       A-1                  4              A
6  CAR2       B-5                  1              B
7  CAR3       C-2                  2              C
8  CAR3       B-8                  1              B
9  CAR3       B-3                  2              B

dfB =
      Part   Car Container_Type
8    Part9  CAR2              B
0    Part1  CAR1              A
1    Part2  CAR1              A
2    Part3  CAR1              B
3    Part4  CAR1              E
9   Part10  CAR1              A
12  Part13  CAR1              A
4    Part5  CAR2              A
5    Part6  CAR2              A
6    Part7  CAR2              A
13  Part14  CAR2              B
7    Part8  CAR3              B
10  Part11  CAR3              B
11  Part12  CAR3              B
```

In dfA, its is known which car contains what time of containers with a specified capacity.

In dfB, it is known which part needs to be in which car and type of container.
the sum of all parts for a car is the same as the sum of the capacities of the containers in dfA.

My Goal: I would like to 'assign' parts randomly to an container with the right type. After a container is 'full' the rest of the parts should be assigned to another container with the right type.Ideally it would return something like this:

```
result =     
               Part   Car Container_Type Container_assign
    0    Part1  CAR1              A              A-2
    1    Part2  CAR1              A              A-2
    2    Part3  CAR1              B              B-2
    3    Part4  CAR1              E              E-1
    9   Part10  CAR1              A              A-1
    12  Part13  CAR1              A              A-1
    4    Part5  CAR2              A              A-1
    5    Part6  CAR2              A              A-1
    6    Part7  CAR2              A              A-5
    8    Part9  CAR2              B              B-2
    13  Part14  CAR2              B              B-5
    7    Part8  CAR3              B              B-8
    10  Part11  CAR3              B              B-8
    11  Part12  CAR3              B              B-3
```

Please note that they can be assigned randomly over the containers, **as long as the capacity requirement is met and the parts are in the right type of container and right car/ULD**.

** EDIT # 2 ** 
@Colonel Beauvel: Here is your code with a little adjustment by me after diving into the try function, which was totally new for me.

```
for i, r in dfB.iterrows():
    mask = (dfA['count']!=0) & (dfA['Container_type']==r['Container_Type']) & (dfA['CAR']==r['CAR'])
    df   = dfA[mask]
    try:
        l.append(df.iloc[0]['Container'])
        dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] = dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] - 1
    except Exception as e:
        l.append('Not Assigned')

dfB['Container_assign']=l
```

Returns this:

```
      Part   CAR Container_Type Container_assign
0    Part9  CAR2              B              B-4
1    Part1  CAR1              A              A-2
2    Part2  CAR1              A              A-2
3    Part3  CAR1              B              B-2
4    Part4  CAR1              E              E-1
5   Part10  CAR1              A     Not Assigned
6   Part13  CAR1              A     Not Assigned
7    Part5  CAR2              A              A-1
8    Part6  CAR2              A              A-1
9    Part7  CAR2              A              A-1
10  Part14  CAR2              B              B-5
11   Part8  CAR3              B              B-8
12  Part11  CAR3              B              B-3
13  Part12  CAR3              B              B-3
```

For example purposes, I changed the capacity of A-6 to zero in order to get 2 not assinged parts back. It worked!

```
  Container   CAR  Capcity_container Container_type  count
0       E-1  CAR1                  1              E      0
1       A-2  CAR1                  2              A      0
2       B-2  CAR1                  1              B      0
3       A-6  CAR1                  0              A      0
4       B-4  CAR2                  1              B      0
5       A-1  CAR2                  4              A      1
6       B-5  CAR2                  1              B      0
7       C-2  CAR3                  2              C      2
8       B-8  CAR3                  1              B      0
9       B-3  CAR3                  2              B      0
```

How do I use else or finally to print something like "All parts are assinged" the capacity meets the number of parts and everything is assinged, in other words, no errors? When i add it, it returns that for every part.
**Edit #3**

I think this does the trick, very simple...

```
l = []
dfA['count'] = dfA['Capcity_container']
erroryesno = 'All parts are Assinged'
for i, r in dfB.iterrows():
    mask = (dfA['count']!=0) & (dfA['Container_type']==r['Container_Type']) & (dfA['CAR']==r['CAR'])
    df   = dfA[mask]
    try:
        l.append(df.iloc[0]['Container'])
        dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] = dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] - 1
    except Exception as e:
        l.append('Not Assigned')
        erroryesno = 'Some are not assinged'
print erroryesno
dfB['Container_assign']=l
```

Comment: just to let you know there are not enough container capacity for B type on the example you provide.

Comment: Hi Colonel Beauvel, you are totally right, sorry. I made this dummy data and edited it while making the question for readability. I probably made a mistake there. I edited it! Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Did you try the below?

Comment: I just did and it works perfectly when the capacities fit the number of parts. In your code you suggest to use try, except when this is the case. I really like it and would like to implement it so that when there is "no room" that the part gets "Not Assigned" in the Container_Assign. I dived into this function tonight and I tried the code mentioned above but unfortunately it always stopped running on decreasing the container capacity (So the code does not continue -> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0). I think I fixed it with the code above! What do you think?

Comment: it is indeed a possibility! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to iterate through `dfB` rows and take the first corresponding container available in `dfA`. This container capacity is thus decreased by one:

```
l = []
dfA['count'] = dfA['Capcity_container']

for i, r in dfB.iterrows():
    mask = (dfA['count']!=0) & (dfA['Container_type']==r['Container_Type']) & (dfA['car']==r['car'])
    df   = dfA[mask]
    try:
        l.append(df.iloc[0]['Container'])
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Not anymore container for this type'
        raise e
    dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] = dfA.ix[df.index[0],'count'] - 1

dfB['container_assign']=l
```

Comment: Hi Colonel, thanks, i'm going to try this in on the real data. Since the dataframe is large, the exception is a very nice addition! I will come back with the results!

Comment: Hi Colonel Beavel, first of all, thank you very much for helping me! I think the solution you provided is almost right. In your code does not take car of different cars. I tried to make it work on a key that combines the Car column with the Container Column, but that doesnt work either. I edited the dummy data as such that you can see what is incorrect at the moment and changed the names of ULD into Car to make the dummy data more intuitive. Any ideas on how to finish?

Comment: I udated my solution. It is quite easy since you just need to add car filtering in the mask ... but still your working example creates an error since there are not enough container regarding the couple (car, container_type)